# RecyclerView on item click starts wrong activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new to Android and tried to start new activity when `RecyclerView` item is clicked. After click on item, toast appears and redirect to `MainActivity`, but I need to redirect on `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`. Where I am mistaken?

Code is from `UserAdvertisementListActivity`:

```
 recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            UserAdvertisementListObject advertisementList = UserAdvertisementList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), advertisementList.getFromCity()
                    + " - " + advertisementList.getToCity() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), UserAdvertisementItemActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("from_city", advertisementList.getFromCity());
            intent.putExtra("to_city", advertisementList.getToCity());
            intent.putExtra("number_of_places", advertisementList.getNumberOfPlaces());
            intent.putExtra("price", advertisementList.getPrice());
            intent.putExtra("datetime", advertisementList.getDatetime());
            intent.putExtra("info", advertisementList.getInfo());
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
```

Run window:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:411771599 intent:Intent { cmp=com.vladimirspucko.organizer/.activity.UserAdvertisementItemActivity (has extras) } 
I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.vladimirspucko.organizer, PackageName:com.vladimirspucko.organizer 
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:411771685 intent:Intent { cmp=com.vladimirspucko.organizer/.activity.MainActivity }
```

I can add other code. Just let me know about that if it's necessary!

Comment: Can you show me how you assign the mContext value ?

Comment: is there adapter class or not?

Comment: @iCantC `Context context = rootView.getContext()` and `mContext = context`

Comment: @JimaleAbdi class that `extends RecyclerView.Adapter`? I have such adapter for `RecyclerView` list.

Comment: Refer [this](https://hackernoon.com/android-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-getadapterposition-a-better-way-3c789baab4db)

Comment: Are you sure it's opening `MainActivity`? Did you possibly use the wrong layout in `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`'s `setContentView()`?

Comment: @MR.HAPPY can you change your line for `mContext` like this, `Context mContext = this` , I am hoping that your `UserAdvertisementListActivity` extends `Activity` at-least at some level in hierarchy.

Comment: @iCantC if `UserAdvertisementListActivity` extends `Fragment`?

Comment: @MikeM. `setContentView()` layout is not wrong in `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`. Edited my question, check the response from `Run` window

Comment: Well, a `startActivity()` call isn't going to just launch the wrong `Activity` class by mistake. Are you sure you're looking at the right code? Is that exactly as you're running it now? Are you starting `MainActivity` anywhere in `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`?

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks all for help and sorry, this is my mistake in `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`. I am checking in this `Activity` if user is logged in and it returned false that's why app was redirecting me to `MainActivity`. What I should do now with question and right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for help and sorry. This is my mistake in `UserAdvertisementItemActivity`. I am checking in this `Activity` if user is logged in and it returned false. That's why app was redirecting me to `MainActivity`.
Other code is working fine.

Comment: if it is possible pls choose my answer as an right answer , thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way to do this...

follow below steps please :

**First)** build public Interface inside your Adapter and then make a private Instance for it

**Second)** use setOnClickListener for your ViewHolder Item inside onBindViewHolder method in your Adapter and call one of the Interface method's

**Third)** go to MainActivity and implement the Interface that we created in First step then you should override the Interface methods in MainActivity , then use startActivity .

**First Step**

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface AdapterCallback {

    void onClickCallback(UserAdvertisementListObject advertisementList);

}

private AdapterCallback adapterCallback;

//...
```

**Second Step**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    viewHolder.YourItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    UserAdvertisementListObject advertisementList = UserAdvertisementList.get(i);

                    adapterCallback.OnClickCallBack(advertisementList);

                }
            });
    //...
```

**Final Step**

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourAdapter.AdapterCallback{
    @Override
    public void onClickCallback(UserAdvertisementListObject advertisementList) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserAdvertisementItemActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("from_city", advertisementList.getFromCity());
        intent.putExtra("to_city", advertisementList.getToCity());
        intent.putExtra("number_of_places", advertisementList.getNumberOfPlaces());
        intent.putExtra("price", advertisementList.getPrice());
        intent.putExtra("datetime", advertisementList.getDatetime());
        intent.putExtra("info", advertisementList.getInfo());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `YourItem` in second step at `viewHolder.YourItem.setOnClickListener`?

Comment: it is another question and i will answer in another answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer :

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.yourView , viewGroup , false);
        return new YourAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }
    //...

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView YourItem; // assuming that YourItem is a TextView


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            YourItem= itemView.findViewById(R.id.YourItemId);//  it is an item in the layout that you defined in onCreateViewHolder method


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I hope that this could be helpful